# How to handle object vs Array in Interface effectively

Tags: typescript

I am running into an issue with a data Interface. My API returns me the data in a format which looks something like this

```
export interface IApiResponse {
    Success: boolean;
    Error: string;
    Message: string;
    RowCount: number;
    Data: [];
  }
```

this works fine as long as the Data is actually an array which is often the case. But when I get lets say the detail of a contact it is only a object in Data which is not an array. So my question is there a way to handle this or is the only way to create 2 interfaces where one is for a response where data is array the other when it is object.

Comment: You can specify two types like this: Data: Array | Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a data type by defining the interface as follows:

```
export interface IApiResponse<T> {
  Success: boolean;
  Error: string;
  Message: string;
  RowCount: number;
  Data: T;
}
```

Then depending on your API endpoint, you can specify the type:

```
function someApiCall(): IApiResponse<MyDataType[]> {
  ...
}
```

Comment: That works, i am wondering is there a way to use a default Datatype if T is not provided ? I am asking to see if there is a easy way to migrate which makes T optional and if T is not provided it would default to array.

Comment: @ConfusedCoder: You should be able to do something like `interface IApiResponse<T = any[]> { ... }`